# Is it possible to write a function adding two integers without control flow and strictly bitwise operations?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I misunderstood a question that said to add two integers using bitwise operations. I did not use any control flow and could not do it. After giving up, all the solutions I found use control flow to accomplish this whether it be an `if`, `while`, `for`, recursion, etc,. Is there a proof that is can\cannot be accomplished?

Comment: It's done all the time. Check out [adders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)).

Comment: What sort of integers? For fixed length integers it is trivial (just unroll the loop by the maximum amount that may be needed, unnecessary iterations will have no effect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a fixed length integer, you can just unroll a ripple carry adder. In the worst case, a carry signal has to propagate all the way from the least significant bit to the most significant bit.

Like this (only slightly tested) (to avoid the C-purists' wrath, I will call this C# code)

```
int add_3bits(int x, int y)
{
    int c = x & y;
    x = x ^ y;
    y = c << 1;
    //
    c = x & y;  //  \
    x = x ^ y;  //  | for more bits, insert more of these blocks
    y = c << 1; //  /
    //
    // optimized last iteration
    return (x ^ y) & 7; // for more bits, change that mask
}
```

If you do it for as many bits as your integer will hold, you won't need the mask in the end.

That's not very efficient, clearly. For 3 bits it's fine, but for 32 bits it becomes quite long. A [Kogge-Stone adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kogge-Stone_Adder) (one of the O(log n) delay adder circuits) is also surprisingly easy to implement in software (in hardware you have to deal with a lot of wires, software doesn't have that problem).

For example: (verified using [my website](http://haroldbot.nl/?q=let+p+%3D+x+%5E+y%2C+g+%3D+x+%26+y%2C+p2+%3D+p+%26+%28p+%3C%3C+1%29%2C+g2+%3D+g+%7C+%28p+%26+%28g+%3C%3C+1%29%29%2C+p3+%3D+p2+%26+%28p2+%3C%3C+2%29%2C+g3+%3D+g2+%7C+%28p2+%26+%28g2+%3C%3C+2%29%29%2C+p4+%3D+p3+%26+%28p3+%3C%3C+4%29%2C+g4+%3D+g3+%7C+%28p3+%26+%28g3+%3C%3C+4%29%29%2C+p5+%3D+p4+%26+%28p4+%3C%3C+8%29%2C+g5+%3D+g4+%7C+%28p4+%26+%28g4+%3C%3C+8%29%29%2C+g6+%3D+g5+%7C+%28p5+%26+%28g5+%3C%3C+16%29%29+in+x+%5E+y+%5E+%28g6+%3C%3C+1%29+%3D%3D+x+%2B+y))

```
static uint add_32bits(uint x, uint y)
{
    uint p = x ^ y;
    uint g = x & y;

    g |= p & (g << 1);
    p &= p << 1;

    g |= p & (g << 2);
    p &= p << 2;

    g |= p & (g << 4);
    p &= p << 4;

    g |= p & (g << 8);
    p &= p << 8;

    g |= p & (g << 16);

    return x ^ y ^ (g << 1);
}
```