# How to add bits using bitwise?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I was trying to figure out how to add bits (up to 2 bytes) using only the following bitwise operations: ~ & ^ | << >>. I've been trying for a while with no luck. I was wondering if anyone knew how.

```
int logicalByteAdd(int x, int y) {

return ;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_adder

Comment: See also, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20494087/555045 (or any of the thousand duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned short add(unsigned short a, unsigned short b)
{
    unsigned short carry = a & b;
    unsigned short result = a ^ b;
    while(carry != 0)
    {
        unsigned short shiftedcarry = carry << 1;
        carry = result & shiftedcarry;
        result ^= shiftedcarry;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Proof of Correctness](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eae4de12aa7390a8) provided by [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck)

Comment: Since comments can be deleted without warning, feel free to copy the link into the actual answer if you want.  Or not, as you desire.

Comment: I understand this, but how can you do it without using the any functions such as while,if,etc.