# How is XOR applied when determining carry?

Tags: bit-manipulation, xor, gameboy

I'm working on a gameboy emulator. One of the CPU operations I need to implement is the adding of a byte `n` to the stack pointer `sp` (opcode `E8`). The carry flag needs to be set if there is a carry from bit 7. I've looked at two implementations for this operation and they both follow the same carry detection logic. The code for this is roughly as follows:

```
int result = (sp + n) & 0xFFFF
boolean carry = ((sp ^ n ^ result) & 0x100) != 0
```

I have worked through this logic with a few examples and it does work, but I simply don't get *how* it works. I understand how `xor` works but what's the logic behind its application here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addition can be written as:

```
a + b = a ^ b ^ (c << 1)
```

Where `c` is the carry-out for every bit (`c << 1` is the carry-in). This can also be used as a way to [implement addition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20500295/555045).

Therefore if the `a ^ b` part is XORed out of the sum again, we're left with `c << 1`. Bit 8 of that is the carry-out of bit 7.

Comment: Took some time to work through what you explained, but I got it, thanks!